# Exoplayer Play From Http (non Https) Urls with Media Items or Media Source [ 2022 ]

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to play videos from urls using http protocol inside exoplayer in android app using **JAVA**.

i had tried the below method in manifest

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

that does not work for me on minimumsdk 23.

I have tested in android v7.1 and android 11.

Later i had came to know that i have to use DefaultHttpFactory / OKhttp from [here](https://exoplayer.dev/network-stacks.html)

But i cant get good samples or implementation over internet.

I had implemented okhttp in gradle

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.x.x'
```

but i dont know how to implement this methods or function in **JAVA**.

How to solve this with okhttp or is there a better solution?

***Guys i found the solution :***

This works for me with out any external library for HLS.

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory().setAllowCrossProtocolRedirects(true);
HlsMediaSource hlsMediaSource =
        new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .setAllowChunklessPreparation(false) // use it only if needed
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri)); // pass your url
exoPlayer.addMediaSource(hlsMediaSource);
exoPlayer.prepare();
exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
exoPlayer.play();
```